# setText in Java isn't working

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm learning in Java, and I'm trying do this settext work, but I'm not getting

> ```
> public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
> {
>     try {
>         (new Visual()).connect("COM4", "1");
>         (new Visual()).connect("COM6", "2");
>     } catch ( Exception e ) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             new Visual().setVisible(true);
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

```
void connect ( String portName, String linha ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            status_porta2.setText(portName);
            .....

        }
    }    
}
```

I'm searching change a label text in this function, but isn't working.. What are happening?
Thanks

Comment: What does _isn't working_ mean?

Comment: Label text is not changed

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see what happens in the `connect` method?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Lacking further information, I would advise "Don't block the EDT".

Comment: The connect function works fine, only not change the text..

Comment: Is `commPort` really an `instanceof` `SerialPort`?

Comment: What is `status_porta2`?

Comment: @peeskillet I edited the SerialPort code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer status_porta2 is a text label

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the thread connect?

Comment: What's a "text label"?  What type of Class is it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer javax swing JLabel

Comment: I would imagine that with all the `new Visual()` statements, what you are seeing on the screen isn't what you are changing...

Comment: @MadProgrammer and if I put the connect function in a new class, how I do to call the JLabel (to set text)?

Comment: It's not a matter of moving connect, it's a matter of using the same instance `Visual` with which you connect with that you show on the screen

Comment: @MadProgrammer and how I can fix this? It's a COM Port connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are creating multiple instances of `Visual`, two which you open a connection and one you show on the screen.

None of these have any connection to each other, meaning what's on the screen isn't what's being managed/manipulated.

Instead, the instance you use to connect to the port should be the instance you show...

For example...

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Visual v1 = new Visual();
                v1.connect("COM4", "1");
                v1.setVisible(true);

                Visual v2 = new Visual();
                v2.connect("COM6", "2");
                v2.setVisible(true);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked, thank you very much :) But, it's possible create only one Visual?

Comment: Maybe with a COM's array

Comment: Then you need consider moving the connection to a new class, maybe based on a `JPanel` instead of a `JFrame` and add each of these to the frame as required.  Personally, I would create a "Connection" class which was responsible for managing the connections and a UI component which was responsible for displaying state of the connection

Comment: If I create a Connection class, how I do to call the JLabel from another class?

Comment: You would need some kind of callback listener which the `Connection` class could use to raise different events, based on what notifications you want to raise.  The UI would then register it's own implementation of this listener with the `Connection` class and simply make the updates to the UI as required when an event is raised

Comment: This is a basic observer pattern [for example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) and [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and is the bases for the [Swing listener API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)

Comment: Sure, I'll try build a project with this base. Thank you very much by help :)